# Pi3 Act blinks once, no boot

Tags: boot, troubleshooting, act

I have got a problem with my Paspberry Pi 3 that my girlfriend put away on a drawer.

I cant boot it any more, I have tried the SD card in another pi, and it boots, even tried a diffrent SD card that also boot on the other one.

The power led is on, but the green act led just blink once, and nothing more. I am afraid that the pie is dead. It was in a drawer that cointaned a strong magnet to.

Any diagnostic I can run to check?

Comment: Read https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern - see if that helps

Comment: it may be a failure that is caused by a static electricity discharge during handling, not the magnet

Answer (score 0):

From elinux:

> Green LED blinks in a specific pattern 1 flash: possibly you have a
>   Rpi from Micron. Take a good look at the processor if it says M with
>   an orbit around it. Using the lastest software ( >= sept 2013 ) will
>   solve your problem. And make sure you have a 4Gb SD card: a 2Gb
>   doesn't work.

Comment: The OP has a Raspberry Pi3 - so obviously he doesn't have a Micron or even a 4GB SD.